# Can encryption using RijndaelManaged produce spaces in the output?

Tags: .net, encryption

I'm trying to implement a requirement in our system that all strings be trimmed before going into the database. There is a layer in our system where I could handle this in one place, but I'm concerned that I might break encrypted strings if I do.

I know the encryption produces some non-alphanumeric characters, but are these limited to non-whitespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most encryption algorithms - including Rijndael - work on *binary* data, not text. There's no concept of a space (or a non-alphanumeric character) within binary data.

If you *must* store encrypted data as text, you'll need to convert it from the binary data (e.g. a byte array) into text first. One simple way of doing that is to use Base64 (e.g. `Convert.ToBase64String(data)`) - and Base64 never includes spaces using the standard codabet.

So to summarize

- If possible, store encrypted data in binary form (e.g. in an IMAGE field)
- If you *have* to store it in a text field, convert it in an appropriate way, e.g. using Base64. *Don't* use something like `Encoding.UTF8`, as the encrypted data is *not* UTF-8-encoded text.
- Base64 doesn't include spaces, so that aspect shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks! I should know better - I actually studied cryptography. Your statement "Base64 doesn't include spaces" made it all click again though. Yes, we do actually Base64 encode the output and hence I won't have problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rinjdael and, more generally, every encryption algorithm may produce spaces in its output. You may want to encode this binary data in a way that prevents spaces, if really needed. I suggest you, however, to just store the data as it is if possible. Many RDBMS provide binary storage support: SQL Server, for example, supports the *varbinary* data type.